# Angle between median and altitude from the 80° angle of a 40-60-80 triangle

Tags: geometry

> The angles of a triangle are 40°, 60° and 80°. What is the angle between the median and the altitude from the 80° vertex?

I can solve this problem if one of the angle is a right angle. I can also find angle between angle bisector and altitude. It seems to me that in this problem, angle bisector and median would be same. But how to prove that?
What if the angles are variables? Can there be a general formula for it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: Firstly, draw a diagram with a protractor, pencil and ruler. Then stablish (provided you can) what you know about Altitudes and Medians. For some background reading, check http://pinkmonkey.com/studyguides/subjects/geometry/chap2/g0202401.asp

Comment: $17.8°$ you can use GeoGebra as geometric calculator

Comment: If angle bisector and median from one vertex are the same, then the triangle is necessarily isosceles, with the legs from that vertex being congruent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diagram is below.  You are asking for angle $DBE$.  Ignoring the coordinates shown, we might as well choose to make $AD=1$, which makes $AB=2$.  We can get $AC=\sin 80^\circ \frac 2{\sin 40^\circ}\approx 3.064$ from the law of sines.  $BD=\sqrt 3, DE=\frac 12 AC-1 \approx 0.532, DEB=\arctan \frac {0.532}{\sqrt 3}\approx 16.17^\circ$

[image]